# Condition probability involving 3 events

Tags: probability

Peter is considering sending a letter to his mother inside Canada to
report his father's death in Toronto. The probability that Peter
write the letter is 0.8. The probability that the mail will not lose the letter is 0.9.
The probability that the postman will deliver the letter is 0.9. Knowing that Peter's mother
did not receive the letter, what is the conditional probability that Peter did not write it?

I thought about setting up a 'probability tree'. The situations in which Peter's mother does not receive the letter are shaded in the picture. They
represent the reduced sample space of the conditional probability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A,B$, and $C$ denote the events where Peter writes the letter, the mail is not lost, and the postman delivers the letter, respectively, where $\mathsf P(A)=0.8$, $\mathsf P(B)=0.9$, and $\mathsf P(C)=0.9$. Let $R$ denote the event that the letter is received. You could create a probability tree as you say. The ways in which the mail is not received is as follows:

[image]

Then the desired probability is simply the average

$$\frac{0.2}{0.2+0.08+0.072}\approx0.568$$

Alternatively, Bayes' theorem gives

$$\mathsf P\left(A^C\mid R^C\right)=\frac{\mathsf P\left(A^C\cap R^C\right)}{\mathsf P\left(R^C\right)}=\frac{\mathsf P\left(A^C\right)}{\mathsf P\left(R^C\right)}=\frac{0.2}{1-\mathsf P(A)\cdot\mathsf P(B)\cdot\mathsf P(C)}\approx0.568$$

where $\mathsf P\left(A^C\cap R^C\right)=\mathsf P\left(A^C\right)$ since if Peter does not write the letter then surely the letter will not be received.